# How to test window objects using jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a class which returns values depending on values present in window object.

`window.test = 123;`

I want to mock the window object's test property to 123 value to be able to test correctly.

I tried `Object.defineProperty`, using global instead, but nothing seems to work. Seems like a trivial question but not able to find the answer on google or elsewhere. Please advice.

Answer (score 4):

In case `window` exists (i.e. Jest runs with JSDOM, which is done by default) it should be:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  window.test = 123;
});

afterEach(() => {
  delete window.test;
});
```

In case it doesn't exist, it's:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  global.window = { test: 123 };
});

afterEach(() => {
  delete global.window;
});
```

Depending on whether `window` is used elsewhere, it may be beneficial to back it up to temporary variable in `beforeEach` and restore in `afterEach`.